# Java import util.Arrays failed after installation of Tomcat 8, How to resolve?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6

I'm using Tomcat 6.0 in eclipse in Windows. I tried to install tomcat 8. Later when i tried to run my project on tomcat 6 in eclipse, it showed "Cannot locate JAR file". then i tried changing the run-time environment and edited server JRE to "Java" from "Workbench Default JRE", server started but "Arrays" not imported while arraylist and other under util is imported. Then i switched back to Workbench Default JRE but nothing has changed.

I have tomcat 7 in my PC, which im not using. Please have a look at the screenshot 
[image]

In the console it is noted:

"INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre/bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Intel\INDE\media_sdk_6.0.0.349\bin\x64;C:\Intel\INDE\media_sdk_6.0.0.349\bin\win32;C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\bin\x64;C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\bin\x86;C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\bin\Pin;C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\bin\GTPin;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex;C:\Android;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
"

Please help me solve this issue. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: `Project` >> `Clean...` and rebuild.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  Tried, no change

Answer (score 2):

I reformatted the output for your path in the console output, replacing each semi colon with a linebreak to make it readable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre\bin
C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre/bin/client
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre/bin
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Intel\INDE\media_sdk_6.0.0.349\bin\x64
C:\Intel\INDE\media_sdk_6.0.0.349\bin\win32
C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\bin\x64
C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\bin\x86
C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\bin\Pin
C:\Intel\INDE\code_builder_5.1.0.25\bin\GTPin
C:\Perl64\site\bin
C:\Perl64\bin
c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex
C:\Android
C:\Windows\System32
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
.
```

It's a bit of a mess, and two things stand out:

[1](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/07/windows-oracle-java-path.html) There are several "java" entries, which appear in the following order:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre\bin
C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre/bin/client
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre/bin
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin
```

You need to clean those up. Pay special attention to **C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath**. See [Oracle Java on Windows: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/07/windows-oracle-java-path.html) for details on how it works.

[2] You have several entries that appear more than once:

```
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\Windows\System32
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

You also need to clean those up; there is no reason to have more than one entry for anything.

Also:

- Uninstall any versions of Java and Tomcat that you don't use.
- Be sure to also delete any directories and files that weren't removed by the uninstall process.
- Remove any entries on your path which refer to directories which do not exist.

Having cleaned up your installation and your path, reboot and try again. Update your post if you still have problems, detailing which version(s) of Java and Tomcat are installed, and which versions you are actually using.

I realize that this approach won't necessarily solve your problem, but since the path has issues it's pointless speculating on what might fix your problem; your path definitely needs attention regardless, so fix that first.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have now uninstalled all previous versions of Java, JDK starting fresh installation of JDK 6. Ill update once finished setting up all